# How do I update an proggress bar after some time, and reset if some data is received?

Tags: react-native

Let me explain.
I have one screen called "Ranking" where I have an list of racers and their positions. Each line is a sub-component called "RankingItem". In the ranking screen, I have all data coming from global state (Redux) and passed to sub-component using props. This is working fine.
Now, in this sub-component (each item in ranking) I have do put a proggress bar. This proggress bar ranges from 0 to 1,  this must be the same as from 0 to medium time (im miliseconds). Ex: my average time is 123566. 0=0 and 1=123566 for the progress bar.
The main problem is how do I update/manage this proggress bar?
I know that I must use setInterval to update my component state, to the proggress will change. I'm trying to do this inside this line component (RankingItem), but time to time, two ow more proggress are updated ate same time, and shouldn't, sunce only one row are updated every 5 seconds (in my simulation).
Also, when racert gets another lap, this proggress should be reset and I don't know how to to this, since the only function that I think I could use will be depreceated in the future.

My redux state has:

```
{
tx_id: 2,
last_time: 1234,
average_time: 1234,
laps: {{...},{...}.{...}]
}
```

I need to 'reset' proggress bat when number of laps are changed (increased) and use 'average' to make min/max of proggress. I'm kind lost here.

More info: I have and 'global' TCP component and when new lap is arrived, it call an reducer to add this lap to global "Race" state, which is an array of all racers (the example above).

Complement: this is my "RankingItem" Object:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {View} from 'react-native';
import { Text, ListItem } from 'native-base';
import {getPilotName,msToTime} from '../../../util/util';
import {translate} from '../../../i18n';
var i18n_opt = {scope: "ranking"};
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-native-easy-grid";
import ProgressBar from 'react-native-progress/Bar';

import styles from "../styles";

class RankingItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = [];

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(this._updatePg());
        }, 1000)

    }

    componentDidUpdate(previous) {

        const tx_id = this.props.data.item.tx_id;
        var tmp = this.state;
        if (!tmp[tx_id]) {
            tmp[tx_id] = {
                pg: 0,
                step: 0.01,
                laps: 0,
                last_time: 0
            }
        }

        if (previous.data.item.laps.length != this.props.data.item.laps.length) {
            tmp[tx_id].pg = 0;
            tmp[tx_id].laps = this.props.data.item.laps.length;
            tmp[tx_id].last_time = this.props.data.item.last_time;

            this.setState(tmp);
        }


    }

    _updatePg() {

        const item = this.props.data.item;
        const tx_id = item.tx_id;

        var tmp = this.state;
        if (tmp[tx_id]) {

            tmp[tx_id].pg = tmp[tx_id].pg + tmp[tx_id].step;

        }

        this.setState(tmp);        

    }





    render() {
        const {data} = this.props;        
        const {position,tx_id,total_time,last_time,best_lap,best_time,diff,laps} = data.item;
        const pg =  this.state[tx_id] ?  this.state[tx_id].pg : 0;

        return (
            <ListItem onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("PersonalRank",{tx_id})} NoIndent style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 0, paddingTop: 0, marginBottom: 0, paddingBottom: 5, marginLeft: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginRight: 0}}>
                <Grid>
                    <Col size={10}><Text>#{position}</Text></Col>
                    <Col size={90}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col size={67}><Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 14}}>{getPilotName(tx_id)}</Text></Col>
                            <Col size={33}><Text style={{fontSize: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 3}}>{translate('total_time',{...i18n_opt})}: {msToTime(total_time)}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('laps',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('last_lap',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('best_lap',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('best_time',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemHeaderText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>{translate('diff',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>{laps.length}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, {fontWeight: 'bold'}]}>{msToTime(last_time)}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>{best_lap}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, { color: '#90db18', fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>{msToTime(best_time)}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>{diff}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><ProgressBar style={styles.progress} progress={pg} width={null} /></Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Grid>
            </ListItem>
        );

    }
}


export default RankingItem;
```

More updates:
This is what happens. Sometimes more than one proggress 'reset', even if only one lap has received (I'm 100% sure only one lap is received every 5 seconds).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding property to 'race' store called 'pg' (progress) and calling one reducer every 1 second. This reducer update 'pg' property for all itens in 'race' reducer. It's working fine.